# ExecutionFailure in MultiSigWallet contract

Tags: ether, multisignature, fallback-function

I wanted to test a simple use case of MultiSig wallet. To do that I've deployed [gnois MultiSigWallet.sol](https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWallet.sol) to Rinkeby network.

Before testing the multisig functionality I wanted to deposit 0.1 ether to the contract so I invoked the fallback function with value of 100000000000000000 (which is 0.1 eth in wei).

```
/// @dev Fallback function allows to deposit ether.
function()
    payable
    public
{
    if (msg.value > 0)
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
}
```

The transaction succeeds but no ether is transferred to the contract nor I see the expected `Deposit` event in etherscan.

What am I doing wrong? How do I deposit ether to my contract?
BTW - the account I'm using to deposit has a positive balance of 3.85 eth.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like maybe you somehow passed the value 0x010... as data to the fallback function instead of as attached ether. If you're using Remix, you set the value of the transaction in the upper right corner of the UI.

Comment: Right, I'm using remix and inserted the value next to the fallback label where it actually should be at the top 'value' field.  Feel free to post it as an answer (I'll accept)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using properly remix. In order to send ether from current EOA to the contract you must put the desired amount in the “Value” box, just in the righ upper part of the “run” panel, THEN click the fallback tab.

[image]